# Migrations not running and throwing error for __EFMigrationsHistory

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have Dot net Core 2.2.1 and Entity Framework Core 2.1.3 and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.0.0 I can not upgrade any of these as this is related to AWS Lambda function which support dot net core 2.2.1 Now when i run Add-Migration InitialCreate it creates the migration and when i type Update-Database it thows an error which is given below

```
    fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (132ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', 
    CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
      VALUES (20190625105712_initialCreate, 2.1.8-servicing-32085);
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at or near "_initialCreate"
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadMessage(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadExpecting[T](Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.Execute(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
Failed executing DbCommand (132ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES (20190625105712_initialCreate, 2.1.8-servicing-32085);
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at or near "_initialCreate"
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadMessage(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadExpecting[T](Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
```

My dbcontext class is as

```
public class TraceUIContext : DbContext
    {
        public TraceUIContext(DbContextOptions<TraceUIContext> options):base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Alarms> Alarms { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to create a script file and changed the file to INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20190625105712_initialCreate', '2.1.8-servicing-32085');
and it executes successfully. I think when running migration it is generating the Values as string but not adding single quote due to which whole migration is failing.

The code generated by migration is as

```cs
public partial class initialCreate : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Alarms",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn),
                    GroupNo = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
                    GroupN = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 20, nullable: true),
                    ChannelNo = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
                    ChannelN = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: true),
                    ComputerName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 40, nullable: true),
                    AlarmType = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 20, nullable: true),
                    AlarmSetPoint = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: true),
                    AlarmStart = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    AlarmAcknowleged = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    AlarmAcknowledgedBy = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: true),
                    AlarmEnd = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    AlarmReason = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 40, nullable: true),
                    AlarmAction = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 40, nullable: true),
                    AlarmValue = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 10, nullable: true),
                    AlarmDelay = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 7, nullable: true),
                    AlarmStatus = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 16, nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Alarms", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Alarms");
        }
    }
```

It should run the migrations and should be able to create Script that run without issues.

Comment: Can you post your IDesignTimeDbContextFactory class and connection string (without credentials!).

Comment: @Neil i have posted the context class

Comment: Do you have a class based on `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` ? That is the one that is used when running migrations.